# WooCommerce PayPal internationalization issue

Tags: wordpress, paypal, internationalization, woocommerce

I am setting up a WooCommerce site and it's supposed to be in German.

I have a problem with one translation.

On the checkout page there is the PayPal payment option and there is a div like:

```
<div class="payment_box payment_method_paypal">
    <p>Bezahlen mit Paypal; Sie können mit Kreditkarte bezahlen auch wen Sie keinen PayPal Account besitzen.</p>
</div>
```

The **;** is ugly and the **wen** should be **wenn**. But I didn't find this sentence in any file (.po, .mo, ...) of my WordPress installation. Does this sentence get loaded directly from PayPal somehow? How could I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing... I totally missed that this string can be set in the WooCommerce PayPal settings. :) The wrong default string should be fixed though by the developers.